# BeforeUpload do not trigger upload on promise resolved

Tags: promise, rxjs, antd

Using `React`, and `antd`

I have the following code in my component:

```
<Upload
action={HttpService.getBaseUrl(`post_import_csv`, HttpService.AuditcoreAPIBasePath)}
headers={{"Authorization": `Bearer ${AuthHelper.getAuthKey()}`}}
showUploadList={false}
multiple={false}
beforeUpload={(file: RcFile): PromiseLike<any> => {
    this.setCSV(file);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.state.requestUpload.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
            resolve(file);
            console.log('resolved')
        });
    })
}}></Upload>
```

Basically I want my `beforeUpload` to wait for the user to click on a button before uploading the file. I did so by returning a Promise and waiting for a rxjs Suject that is triggered on button click to resolve the promise. Pretty much following the [doc](https://react-component.github.io/upload/examples/beforeUpload.html)

Here is the button code :

```
<Button
    onClick={(e): void => {
        this.state.requestUpload.next(true);
    }}
    >
    Upload
</Button>
```

It works nice, but the file is never uploaded, I do see my log `resolved` but there is no trace of network call in my console.

Comment: I guess you have to wrap the `<Button>` inside of the `<Upload>` see: https://github.com/react-component/upload/blob/master/examples/customRequest.js#L75-L77

Comment: the button inside is for a different purpose, it's for opening the explorer, anyway I tried and no change (I don't see why this would have changed something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed using this approach which is cleaner :

https://codesandbox.io/s/xvkj90rwkz

Basically, having a custom function that handle upload. It doesn't explain why my tricky solution was not working, but I got it working.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Upload, Button, Icon, message } from 'antd';
import reqwest from 'reqwest';

class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fileList: [],
    uploading: false,
  };

  handleUpload = () => {
    const { fileList } = this.state;
    const formData = new FormData();
    fileList.forEach(file => {
      formData.append('files[]', file);
    });

    this.setState({
      uploading: true,
    });

    // You can use any AJAX library you like
    reqwest({
      url: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76',
      method: 'post',
      processData: false,
      data: formData,
      success: () => {
        this.setState({
          fileList: [],
          uploading: false,
        });
        message.success('upload successfully.');
      },
      error: () => {
        this.setState({
          uploading: false,
        });
        message.error('upload failed.');
      },
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { uploading, fileList } = this.state;
    const props = {
      onRemove: file => {
        this.setState(state => {
          const index = state.fileList.indexOf(file);
          const newFileList = state.fileList.slice();
          newFileList.splice(index, 1);
          return {
            fileList: newFileList,
          };
        });
      },
      beforeUpload: file => {
        this.setState(state => ({
          fileList: [...state.fileList, file],
        }));
        return false;
      },
      fileList,
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Upload {...props}>
          <Button>
            <Icon type="upload" /> Select File
          </Button>
        </Upload>
        <Button
          type="primary"
          onClick={this.handleUpload}
          disabled={fileList.length === 0}
          loading={uploading}
          style={{ marginTop: 16 }}
        >
          {uploading ? 'Uploading' : 'Start Upload'}
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('container'));
```